# Send email with attachment [ Lotus Notes ]

Tags: vba, excel, email

I have two Excel files: one is macro-enabled, one is a blank Excel form.

Scenario:
- Currently, Blank Excel form will be filled manually and attachment in Lotus Notes email and send out externally daily.
- This Excel blank form also will save as a new Excel file with different file name once it is filled with information.

Now, I want to write VBA Excel such that I only need to click button to send out the Excel form attached in Lotus Notes email.

I already found the code as following and it is working:

```
Sub Send_Email_via_Lotus_Notes()
Dim Maildb As Object
Dim MailDoc As Object
Dim Body As Object
Dim Session As Object
'Start a session of Lotus Notes
    Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
'This line prompts for password of current ID noted in Notes.INI
    Call Session.Initialize
'or use below to provide password of the current ID (to avoid Password prompt)
    'Call Session.Initialize("<password>")
'Open the Mail Database of your Lotus Notes
    Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", "D:\Notes\data\Mail\eXceLiTems.nsf")
    If Not Maildb.IsOpen = True Then Call Maildb.Open
'Create the Mail Document
    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("Form", "Memo")
'Set the Recipient of the mail
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("SendTo", "Ashish Jain")
'Set subject of the mail
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("Subject", "Subject Text")
'Create and set the Body content of the mail
    Set Body = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Body")
    Call Body.APPENDTEXT("Body text here")
'Example to create an attachment (optional)
    Call Body.ADDNEWLINE(2)
    Call Body.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", "C:\dummy.txt", "Attachment")
'Example to save the message (optional) in Sent items
    MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
'Send the document
'Gets the mail to appear in the Sent items folder
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("PostedDate", Now())
    Call MailDoc.SEND(False)
'Clean Up the Object variables - Recover memory
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set Body = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing
```

However, I want the attachment filename and email subject to be variable instead of hard-code a static filename and path.

Would anyone please provide some guide?

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters.

```
Sub Send_Email_via_Lotus_Notes(filename as string, emailSubject as string)
Dim Maildb As Object
Dim MailDoc As Object
Dim Body As Object
Dim Session As Object
'Start a session of Lotus Notes
    Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
'This line prompts for password of current ID noted in Notes.INI
    Call Session.Initialize
'or use below to provide password of the current ID (to avoid Password prompt)
    'Call Session.Initialize("<password>")
'Open the Mail Database of your Lotus Notes
    Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", "D:\Notes\data\Mail\eXceLiTems.nsf")
    If Not Maildb.IsOpen = True Then Call Maildb.Open
'Create the Mail Document
    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("Form", "Memo")
'Set the Recipient of the mail
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("SendTo", "Ashish Jain")
'Set subject of the mail
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("Subject", emailSubject)
'Create and set the Body content of the mail
    Set Body = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Body")
    Call Body.APPENDTEXT("Body text here")
'Example to create an attachment (optional)
    Call Body.ADDNEWLINE(2)
    Call Body.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", filename, "Attachment")
'Example to save the message (optional) in Sent items
    MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
'Send the document
'Gets the mail to appear in the Sent items folder
    Call MailDoc.REPLACEITEMVALUE("PostedDate", Now())
    Call MailDoc.SEND(False)
'Clean Up the Object variables - Recover memory
    Set Maildb = Nothing
    Set MailDoc = Nothing
    Set Body = Nothing
    Set Session = Nothing
```